# How do I prove that these two definitions for injective functions are equivalent?

Tags: functions, definition, first-order-logic

Suppose we have a function $f:M \rightarrow N$

First definition of injectiveness:

$\forall a \in M \forall b \in M(f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b)$

Second definition (here $f$ represents the function's graph):

$\forall y \in N \forall a \in M \forall b \in M((a,y)\in f \land (b,y)\in f \implies a=b)$

I have tried to prove the equivalence of the above statements by making use of the fact that:

$\forall x \forall y((x,y)\in f \iff f(x)=y)$

which would allow me to make the following substitutions in the first definition:

$\forall a \in M \forall b \in M(\forall y(f(a)=y \iff y=f(b)) \implies a=b)$

$\forall a \in M \forall b \in M(\forall y((a,y)\in f \iff (b,y)\in f) \implies a=b)$

But after this step I am stuck...

Comment: If the answer solves the problem to your satisfaction, please accept it. If it is not to your satisfaction, please add a comment to the answer explaining your qualms. This is the general etiquette on this website, which you should follow with all of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

The key-point is that $f$ is a function and only under this condition we can use the symbol $f(x)$, because we know that there is only one $y$ such that $(x,y) \in f$.

Thus, when we consider the condition $\forall y [(a,y) \in  f\land (b,y) \in f]$ the above fact implies that $(a,f(a)) \in  f \land (b,f(a)) \in f$, from which: $f(a)=f(b)$.

An thus, from the first definition, we get $a=b$ by Modus Ponens.

Similar for the other direction.